# How can I write a formula so that an addition of +1 or -1 changes a number's value less and less, never reaching +10 or -10?

Tags: functions

I want to write a formula where 1 or -1 may be added to a starting variable of zero, any number of times, but I want to make it so that the rate of increase / decrease decreases infinitely before reaching +10 or -10. The farther the number moves from zero, the less it should be affected by the +1 or -1 input.

I'm not very good with math. How can I do this?

Comment: Hopefully this makes sense. If there's any way I can improve the question or need to clarify, I'm here to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a function like $$f(x) = \frac{10}{x}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1} - 1\right),$$ perhaps?  Here's a plot showing that the function increases from close to $-10$ to close to $10$ but never reaches either in either direction:

[image]

If the transition from $-10$ to $10$ happens too quickly then you might consider scaling $x$, say by replacing it with $x/2$ or something like that.

Comment: This is perfect thank you for showing me how it's done ^_^

Comment: Glad to help :)